# If I have an API app with pagination on database and data treatment in app after retrieve(eg. filter), how deal with return length < size requested

Tags: rest, pagination, architecture

It may be a design limitation tradeoff, but I want to be sure about that.

This is the scenario:

- I`m building an API crud app, focusing on GET method
- I may implement cursor pagination on GET, params `count`, `itemsAfter` and `itemsBefore`
- The pagination will be handled by the database, eg. `[...] WHERE id > :itemsAfter LIMIT :count`
- After the data is retrieved, I need to do some in-memory processing that might be too complex to be performed on database eg.: lookup relationship with other data and filters
- In this scenario, my API response will always return a number of items <= the `count` param requested

Do you think there are ways to solve this design problem?

I was thinking, maybe adding an arbitrary number of a remainder in database LIMIT and keeping track of this cursor? but the problem could still happen, just a better probability to get more items, closer to count.